# Format of date to compare two dates, one coming from mogo database, the other from one http request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to compare to dates to do some logic in a express function.
One date coming from the mongodb and defined in mongoose schema with the Date object holds the format:

```
date: "1991-12-12T00:00:00.000Z"
```

Another date from a http request is a string with format YYYY-MM-DD

```
 http://www.web.com/path1/path2?from=1990-12-31&to=2000-12-31
```

How can do both date comparable to implement some logic in a callback function

```
 if ( "1991-12-12T00:00:00.000Z" > from &&  "1991-12-12T00:00:00.000Z" < to){
           ...some logic here
 }
```

Comment: use moment.js for accurate results and comparisons

Answer (score 1):

Use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com) to determine whether these dates are within the same day or not. 
Also Moment.js includes methods like: "[isBefore](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/)", "[isAfter](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/)", "[isSameOrBefore](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-before/)", "[isSameOrAfter](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-after/)" that you might want to use to achive your goals.

```js
const isSameDay = moment('1991-12-12T00:00:00.000Z', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ')
    .isSame(moment('1991-12-12','YYYY-MM-DD'), 'day');
if(isSameDay) {
  console.log('Dates are within the same day');
} else {
  console.log('Dates are not within the same day');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, that is it. I already had a look in moment but I didn't know about the methods. I was trying wrongly with the comparison operators (>, <).

Comment: @user1881983 Please mark it as answer if it is helpful